# React child component not updating when props change

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to build out a local search in React consisting of a parent component with a search input, and a child component containing a list of search results. I've created a React state object that contains the search query and a list of search results. When the input field is changed, the search is ran to generate a new result set, and both properties (query and results) are updated. The search input is updating as expected, but the child component doesn't re-render despite an update to its prop. I've removed some of the code for brevity, but if you need more information please let me know.

```
export const Search = () => {
  let [searchState, setSearchState] = React.useState({});

  let handleChange = (event) => {
    searchState['results'] = searchProducts(event.target.value);
    searchState['query'] = event.target.value;
    setSearchState(searchState);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <FormControl>
        <Input
          value={searchState.query}
          onChange={handleChange}>
          Search...
        </Input>
      </FormControl>
      <SearchResults results={searchState.results}></SearchResults>
    </div>
  );
};

export const SearchResults = (props) => {
  return (
    <List>
      {props.results?.map((product, index) => (
        <ListItem key={index}>
          <ListItemText primary={product.name}></ListItemText>
        </ListItem>
      ))}
    </List>
  );
};
```

My question is: Why doesn't the SearchResults component get re-rendered when `searchState.results` changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mutate your state object in your `handleChange` function. The component doesn't rerender because `searchState` is still the same object reference from the previous render cycle.

```
let handleChange = (event) => {
  searchState['results'] = searchProducts(event.target.value); // mutation!
  searchState['query'] = event.target.value; // mutation!
  setSearchState(searchState); // safe reference back into state
};
```

You shouldn't mutate state object directly. Use a functional state update and shallow copy existing state into a ***new*** state object reference. Then update the properties you want to update.

```
let handleChange = (event) => {
  const { value } = event.target;

  setSearchState(searchState => ({
    ...searchState,
    results: searchProducts(value),
    query: value,
  }));
};
```

Comment: Thank you, this explains it perfectly!